# No repository found for hub.topic - Scope issue?

Tags: github, github-api, websub

I am trying to subscribe to changes in a particular repository but I'm getting a "No repository found for hub.topic".

Here's my request:

curl -u "*user*" -i  https://api.github.com/hub  -F "hub.mode=subscribe"  -F "hub.topic=https://github.com/iOS-Goodies/iOS-Goodies/events/watch" -F "hub.callback=*callback*"

Given that this curl request follows Github's documentation guidelines and that it works for my own repositories, I assume this is a matter of scope.

Am I unable to subscribe to events on repositories I do not own?

Thanks

Comment: You have to be an administrator of the repository in order to perform that API request. The PubSubHubbub API follows the same permission rules as the [Webhooks API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/): "The Repository Webhooks API allows repository admins to manage the post-receive hooks for a repository. Webhooks can be managed using the JSON HTTP API, or the PubSubHubbub API."

Comment: Damn. Do you know a way of getting near realtime notifications for repositories you want to watch? If PubsubHubbub won't cut it, I guess I'm back to polling

Comment: @jasonrudolph Post the answer so that I can award you the points. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be an administrator of the repository in order to perform that API request. The PubSubHubbub API follows the same permission rules as the [Webhooks API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/): "The Repository Webhooks API allows repository admins to manage the post-receive hooks for a repository. Webhooks can be managed using the JSON HTTP API, or the PubSubHubbub API."